# C# LINQ for tree oriented data structure of classes

Tags: c#, linq, list, tree

I have List where myObj has it own list of objects called example mySubObj.
Object mySubObj has prop string Name.

So I want to create new List base on prop string Name from mySubObj.

I wrote this code, but it seems that it's wrong:

```
var por = msgs.Where(x => x.Parameters
                        .Where(p => p.ParameterName == s).Count() == 1);
```

Can anyone help me with LINQ?

EDIT: This is whole code:

```
 foreach (string s in parameters)
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFolder + "/" + s + ".xls"))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write("No.\tMessage\tMS\tTime\tSC");

                    var por = (from m in msgs
                               from p in m.Parameters
                               where p.ParameterName == s
                               select m).Distinct();


                    List<string> headeri = new List<string>();
                    List<string> vrijednosti = new List<string>();

                    foreach (L3Message p in por)
                    {
                        foreach (Parameter pam in p.Parameters)
                        {
                            TraverseForHeaders(pam, ref headeri);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (string head in headeri)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write("\t" + head);
                    }
                    streamWriter.Write("\n");
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is two of my classes, with this it should be more specified:

```
public class L3Message
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string MessageName { get; set; }
    public string Device { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string ScramblingCode { get; set; }

    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

    public L3Message()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    }}

public class Parameter
{
    public int numOfWhitespaces { get; set; }

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }

    public Parameter Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> SubParameters { get; set; }

    public Parameter()
    {
        SubParameters = new List<Parameter>();
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you want to have all the messages that have some parameter with name x?

Comment: How does this seem wrong? What are you trying to do? What are you getting versus what you except?

Comment: Hmm. I found problem, but not solution, problem is that myObj has both ParameterNames, and this LINQ do what it is supose to do. Except I want in output take myObj witch have only mySubObj with one define ParameterName, another way to say I want role out all subObj with name different than string s. I'll edited question.

Comment: So I want that headers are only ParameterName which are equal with string s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand it at the moment you want to create the "tree" with all parameters removed except the one you specified by name. You should create a copy of the Message for this, because if not you will change the original and cannot recover the "lost" parameters (I say this, because you said in the comments you want it to be temporary).

So with this the code should be more or less like this:

```
        var por = (from m in messages
                   from p in m.Parameters
                   where p.ParameterName == s
                   select new L3Message { Number = m.Number, ...,  Parameters = new List<Parameter> { p } }
                  );
```

Instead of "..." you have to copy the other parameters from message.

All this being said, removing these properties temporarily seems like a bad solution to whatever problem you have. If you want to pass this to another method, can't you change this method to tell it the property it should look at?

**Edit:** Fixed code (second time)

**Edit2:** Fixed code again (now duplicate properties result in additional messages, also see my alternative answer.

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing, except you are running a distinct count on msgs, whereas the OP has a distinct count on parameters. Maybe that is what is wrong, but that is definitely an assumption since the OP does not give what the OP is trying to do

Comment: Sorry no... Still I have all messages!

Comment: Sorry the problem obvious is not in LINQ, it's in L3Message obj... Some of that obj contains both ParameterNames and LINQ take that messeges and expand my header.

Comment: So to rephrase question... How can I temporary exclude those subObj which doesn't have SubparameterName == s?

Comment: Sorry no... I'm really new in C# and .NET, but I know that must be solution in filtering List<myObj> base on prop mySubObj.ParameterName in List<mySubObj> which is prop of myObj.

Comment: What problem do you encounter with the updated code? If you still get all messages returned, it's probably because they all have the parameter set. What value does s have? does it change?

Comment: s can be one of 150 different ParameteName-s, Problem is when my obj from msgs list contain more subParameter with ParamterNames, and i want to exclude these, because I am creating output file with only one subparam and with it subsubparams.

Comment: So what you want is to have the Message object but with all parameters removed except the one that you specified?

Comment: Yes! But to say... Message object have list of Parameter object which have it's own List of Parameter object. I want that first List of parameter object is filtered to only one parameter object which is specified with propertie ParameterName == s. So output is to remove from my list of messages those messages which have not specified obj parameter and if one obj message have that obj and another object, leave that one and remove another from list of that objects. :-) Hope u understand question. Sorry on my English.

Comment: Your second edit code provide this result: My root obj Message properties are all set to null or 0, except prop List<Parameter> (this must not happen), Parameter subobject is nice filtered, but in messages which contains more different Parameter subobject (in it List property), prop List<Parameter> contains more same objects depend on s == ParameterName which your LINQ filtered (it should contain only one Parameter object).

Comment: I want to apologize, It seems that one my L3Message can contain more of same Parameter in it's porp List < Parameter > . EDIT: So if there is more same Parameter obj with same ParameterName prop, I need to insert new L3Message in List < L3Messages > for each of them because they have different  SubParameter.Name values. Sorry again.

Comment: This is solution, code works perfectly!!! Many many thx! Can u look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963931/c-sharp-winforms-populating-treeview-from-listmyobj

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you want. I know this can probably be cleaned into one LINQ statement, but can you test to see if this is indeed what you need first?

```
var hasS = msgs.Where(x=>x.Parameters.Where(p=>p.ParameterName == s).Count() > 0);
var hasOtherThanS = msgs.Where(x=>x.Parameters.Where(p=>p.ParameterName != s).Count() > 0);
var por = hasS.Except(hasOtherThanS);
```

Comment: Sorry no... Output is very confusing. I'm very lost in my code now... I'll continue with this tomorrow (I'm exhausted), guys thanks for help... Hope that tomorrow you will be online :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a second answer, because now that the OP added some more code, there might or might not be another solution to the problem.

Do you really need to remove the parameters from the Messages? Why not change your code like this:

```
foreach (L3Message p in msgs)   
{   
    foreach (Parameter pam in p.Parameters.Where(p => p.ParameterName == s)   
    {   
        TraverseForHeaders(pam, ref headeri);   
    }   
}
```

Like this you keep your messages like they are but the rest of the code simply skips them.